# How can I count all values from database using ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I retrieve data from a database as list of json data using ASP.NET Web API, but I want to count the values based on same values.

My controller code :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server = ...; database = ...; Integrated Security=false; user id = ...; password = ...;");

public IHttpActionResult Getusers()
{
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from users", con); 
        DataTable dts = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dts);

        var apiResult = new ApiResult
        {
            Data = jarr,
            Count = dts.Rows.Count,
            Success = true,
        };

        if (dts.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            return Ok(apiResult);
        }
        else
        {
            return Ok("No data found ...");
        }
}
```

and I have gotten the result as json list of values like this:

```
{
  "Data": [
            {
              "user_name": "Alex",
              "book_name": "The Dragon",
              "book_type": "stories"
            },
            {
              "user_name": "Alex",
              "book_name": "Mirage",
              "book_type": "stories"
            },
            {
              "user_name": "Alex",
              "book_name": "The burning forest",
              "book_type": "stories"
            },
            {
              "user_name": "Alex",
              "book_name": "Traditions of Latin America",
              "book_type": "culture"
            },
            {
              "user_name": "Alex",
              "book_name": "Addis Ababa",
              "book_type": "culture"
            }
          ],
  "Count": 5,
  "Success": true
}
```

Now, how can I get result as a count values? Like this :

```
{
  "Data": [
            {
              "user_name": "Alex",
              "stories": 3,
              "culture": 2
            }
          ],
  "Count": 1,
  "Success": true
}
```

Comment: you can convert your data to a list and use take method in Linq and then get the desired count. the following link may help you. https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/take-operator-in-linq/

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the data in order to achieve the desired output.

1. Retrieve the data from `dts.Rows` and convert it to `IEnumerable`.
2. Group by `user_name` and `book_type` and perform `Count()`.
3. Group by `user_name`. As you want each object containing the `book_type` and `count` as key-value pair. You can use *Newtonsoft.Json.Linq* to add the key-value pair into `JObject` and boxing it (cast as `object` type).

For the `apiResult`, you assign the result from `groupedByUserName` to the `Data` property and the number of `groupedByUserName` records to the `Count` property.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var groupedByUserName = (from DataRow dr in dts.Rows
    select new
    {
        user_name = dr["user_name"].ToString(),
        book_name = dr["book_name"].ToString(),
        book_type = dr["book_type"].ToString()
    })
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.user_name, x.book_type })
    .Select(x => new 
            {
                user_name = x.Key.user_name,
                book_type = x.Key.book_type,
                count = x.Count()
            })
    .GroupBy(x => x.user_name)
    .Select(x =>
            {
                JObject jObj = new JObject();
                jObj.Add("user_name", x.Key);

                jObj.Merge(JObject.FromObject(x.ToDictionary(y => y.book_type, y => y.count)));

                return jObj.ToObject<object>();
            })
    .ToList();

var apiResult = new ApiResult
{
    Data = groupedByUserName,
    Count = groupedByUserName.Count,
    Success = true,
};
```

---

Alternative depends on your DBMS (such as SQL Server, Postgres etc.) and version, you can build your query to return with JSON.

For SQL server:

```
SELECT user_name,
       JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(CONCAT('{"', book_type, '":', count, '}'), ','), ']')) AS book_types
FROM (
  SELECT user_name, book_type, COUNT(1) AS count
  FROM users
  GROUP BY user_name, book_type
) A
GROUP BY user_name
```

Next, extract and transform the data from `DataTable` to the desired output.

```cs
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con); 
DataTable dts = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dts);

var groupedByUserName = (from DataRow dr in dts.Rows
    select new
    {
        user_name = dr["user_name"].ToString(),
        book_types = JArray.FromObject(dr["book_types"])
    })
    .Select(x =>
            {
                JObject jObj = new JObject();
                jObj.Add("user_name", x.user_name);

                foreach (JObject book_type in x.book_types)
                {
                    jObj.Merge(JObject.FromObject(book_type));
                }   

                return jObj.ToObject<object>();
            })
    .ToList();

var apiResult = new ApiResult
{
    Data = groupedByUserName,
    Count = groupedByUserName.Count,
    Success = true,
};
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jWvXH6)

Comment: [Query @ SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/55922/9/0) [Demo Answer 2 @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8tmXLo)